# Vbscript - Adding a Word-Addin during script

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, registry, add-in

Ok, I've done this before but I cannot quite get how I did this before. So what I want to do is to deploy a Word 2007 addin which was created using Word, saved as a *.dotm file. I remember something about the registry. And I've tried to add entries at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins`, but I don't know what's exactly supposed to be there? I created a key with the name of the add-in. And inside I put a REG_SZ named "FriendlyName" with the name of the addin. And a REG_DWORD called "LoadBehaviour" with the value of "3". But what I can't understand is where I set the path to the actual *.dotm file?

Comment: Add it into Word by hand and then examine/search the registry to see what Word did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood two concepts for "add-in" in Word. There are template-based add-ins (dotm-files), and COM add-ins (dll-files).
Your approach aims for COM add-ins, which (as COM Library DLL) need to be registered through Regsvr32, and then need to have an entry below the key you mentioned. You'll find more information on MSDN.
However, with a dotm-file, you just load it in Word through the interface (2007: Office-button, option, add-ins). Another way is to distribute it to the user's startup folder, in which case Word loads it automatically on startup.

Comment: Aha. This means that I need to add it to the startup-folder then. It is possible to define my own startup folder isn't it?

Comment: Depends somehow on the goals you want to achieve and if you need to deploy the add-in in a corporate environment. If so, than the recommended way is to define a new startup folder, e.g. C:\corp\word\startup, and distribute the registry entry for that through group policy. Please have a look to this discussion: http://www.officekb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/word-vba-beginners/3606/word-startup-folder